# Towers of Hanoi Visualisation Problems in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I've got a Problem with my Console Output I receive always exceptions and can't fix the bug the solution already worked but the stack grows from top to bottom, so I tried to sort my Elements by
Whitespace.Count to reverse that order hope you can help me, here is my code:

```
public class TvH
{
    #region
    IDictionary<string, int> towerMapping = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"Start", 0}, {"Mitte", 1}, {"Ziel", 2}
    };

    private string emptyTower = "     |     ";
    private int turns = 0;
    Stack<string>[] towers;
    Dictionary<int, string> discs = new Dictionary<int, string>() 
        {
            {1, "-----|-----"},
            {2, " ----|---- "},
            {3, "  ---|---  "},
            {4, "   --|--   "},
            {5, "    -|-    "}
        };
    #endregion

    public TvH(int towerCount)
    {
        towers = new Stack<string>[towerCount];
        initializeTowers();
    }

    private void initializeTowers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < towers.Length; i++)
        {
            towers[i] = new Stack<string>();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= discs.Count; i++)
        {
            towers[0].Push(discs[i]);
            towers[1].Push(emptyTower);
            towers[2].Push(emptyTower);
        }
    }

    public void bewegeScheibe(int n, string a, string b, string c)
    {  
        if (n > 0)
        {
            bewegeScheibe(n - 1, a, c, b);   
            turns++;
            Console.Write("\nZug # ");
            if (turns < 10)
            {
                Console.Write("0");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}      Disc # {1}      {2} --> {3}\n", turns, n, a, c);
            move(a, c);
            bewegeScheibe(n - 1, b, a, c);                
        }
    }

    private void move(string start, string target)
    {
        var element = towers[towerMapping[start]].Pop();
        towers[towerMapping[target]].Push(element);

        printContent();
    }

    private void printContent()
    {
        IList<string> t1 = prepairTowerForPrint(towers[0].GetEnumerator());
        IList<string> t2 = prepairTowerForPrint(towers[1].GetEnumerator());
        IList<string> t3 = prepairTowerForPrint(towers[2].GetEnumerator());

        int i = 0;
        while (i < discs.Count)
        {                
            object ob1 = t1[i];
            object ob2 = t2[i];
            object ob3 = t3[i];

            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", ob1, ob2, ob3);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private IList<string> prepairTowerForPrint(Stack<string>.Enumerator enumerator)
    {
        IList<string> towerList = new List<string>();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            towerList.Add(TryReadNext(enumerator));
        }
        towerList = towerList.OrderByDescending(scheiben => scheiben.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace)).ToList();
        return towerList;
    }

    private string TryReadNext(IEnumerator ce)
    {
        if (ce.MoveNext())
        {
            return (string)ce.Current;
        }
        else
        {
            return emptyTower;
        }
    }     
}
```

thank you very much

Comment: Be more specific: what exception do you recieve and when?

Comment: when I iterate over the lists in my printContent Method I get an out of range exception while building the objects to print, before sorting my recursive move Method worked well I tried jst to beautify Console Output and now everything is broke :D

Comment: well if its a out of range exception then towers[0], [1]... is not initialized when you are trying to access it

Comment: They are initialized but the Count exceeds the number of Discs and I have no guess to fix this Problem with empty poles recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved another way, here's the code if anybody needs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TuermeVonHanoi
{
public class TvH
{
    #region
    IDictionary<string, int> towerMapping = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"start", 0}, {"middle", 1}, {"target", 2}
    };

    private string emptyTower = "     |     ";
    private int turns = 0;
    Stack<string>[] towers;

    IList<string> discs = new List<string>()
    {
        {"-----|-----"},
        {" ----|---- "},
        {"  ---|---  "},
        {"   --|--   "},
        {"    -|-    "}
    };
    #endregion

    public TvH(int towerCount)
    {
        towers = new Stack<string>[towerCount];
        initializeTowers();
    }

    private void initializeTowers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < towers.Length; i++)
        {
            towers[i] = new Stack<string>();
        }

        foreach (var d in discs)
        {
            towers[0].Push(d);
        }
    }

    public void moveAlgorithmic(int n, string a, string b, string c)
    {  
        if (n > 0)
        {
            moveAlgorithmic(n - 1, a, c, b);   
            ++turns;
            Console.Write("\nturn # ");
            if (turns < 10)
            {
                Console.Write("0");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}      disc # {1}      {2} --> {3}\n", turns, n, a, c);
            moveVisual(a, c);
            moveAlgorithmic(n - 1, b, a, c);                
        }
    }

    private void moveVisual(string start, string target)
    {   
        var element = towers[towerMapping[start]].Pop();
        towers[towerMapping[target]].Push(element);                        
        printContent();
    }

    private void printContent()
    {
        IList<string> t1 = prepareTowerForPrint(towers[0].GetEnumerator());
        IList<string> t2 = prepareTowerForPrint(towers[1].GetEnumerator());
        IList<string> t3 = prepareTowerForPrint(towers[2].GetEnumerator());
        int i = 0;
        while (i < discs.Count)
        {
            object ob1 = t1[i];
            object ob2 = t2[i];
            object ob3 = t3[i];           
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", ob1, ob2, ob3);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    private IList<string> prepareTowerForPrint(Stack<string>.Enumerator enumerator)
    {
        IList<string> towerList = new List<string>();
        int count = 0;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            ++count;
            towerList.Add(enumerator.Current);
        }

        int toPush = discs.Count - count;
        for (int i = 0; i < toPush; i++ )
        {
            towerList.Add(emptyTower);
        }
        if (toPush != 0 || toPush != 1)
        {
            towerList = towerList.OrderByDescending(d => d.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace)).ToList();
        }
        return towerList;
    }
}
```

}

instead of initializing all 3 stacks we calculate how many empty pin elements have to be printed out for every stack

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assume that each stack always has five discs, yet in the method `move` you `pop` an element from one and `push` it on another. Hence the error.

So you'd need to remove one element from towers[towerMapping[target]] and add one to towers[towerMapping[start]].

Can I also do a little code review?

Why is `discs` a dictionary? It would make for more sense to make it a List() and simply loop through it:

```
List<string> discs = new List<string>() 
{
    "-----|-----",
    " ----|---- ",
    "  ---|---  ",
    "   --|--   ",
    "    -|-    "
};

foreach(var dics in discs)
{
    towers[0].Push(disc);
    towers[1].Push(emptyTower);
    towers[2].Push(emptyTower);
}
```

Why do you do `towers = new Stack<string>[towerCount];` in the TvH constructor instead of in the method called `initializeTowers()`?

The method `prepairTowerForPrint` contains a typo, the verb is to **prepare**.

Method names in German are a bad idea, IMHO. Also, [method names should be PascalCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).

The only public method is `bewegeScheibe()` but it's parameters are actually part of the TvH class: "Start", "Mitte", "Ziel". It's first parameter is `int n`, which says absolutely nothing; I only figured out what `string a, string b, string c` were expected to be by reading the code.

Comment: well I need all the time 5 elements per stack cause I want to simulate an empty pole so I don't understandwhy this is wrong

Comment: Like I said in my edit: "So you'd need to remove one element from towers[towerMapping[target]] and add one to towers[towerMapping[start]]." (in the `move` method)